# SAPUI5 Variant Management Save Button

Tags: save, sapui5, rendering, variant

expert.

I use the API 「sap.ui.comp.varinats」 to implement variant management.
Save the variant data to S/4 via OData.

The "SAVE" button is invisible, so I want to enable it.
I referred to the article below, but it didn't work.
https://answers.sap.com/questions/12086627/variant-management---save-option.html

I want to enable this "SAVE" button when the view has finished loading, but I have a problem.

I want to get the oVariantSave function using this.getView().ById("vm").
I can get the oVariantSave function in onSelect.
 But I can't get the oVariantSave function in onAfterRendering.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6kCI.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVP07.png)

```js
<View>
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
    xmlns:v="sap.ui.comp.variants" 
    controllerName="Test.controller.View1" displayBlock="true">
    <App id="app">
        <Page id="page" title="{i18n>title}">
            <content>
                <v:VariantManagement id="vm" select="onSelect" save="onSave" enabled="true" manage="onManage" showExecuteOnSelection="false"
                    showShare="false" showSetAsDefault="false" variantItems="{Variants>results}">
                    <v:variantItems>
                        <v:VariantItem text="{Variants>Varname}" key="{Variants>Varkey}" author="{Variants>Userid}"/>
                    </v:variantItems>   
                </v:VariantManagement>

<Controller>
//i can't get oVariantSave function
onAfterRendering: function () {
    var oVariantMgmtControl = this.getView().byId("vm");
}

//i can get oVariantSave function
onSelect: function (oEvent) {
    var oVariantMgmtControl = this.getView().byId("vm");
}
```

Please tell me how to get the oVariantSave function in onAfterRendering 
and enable the "SAVE" button before the user takes action.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Which sapUI5 version are you targeting?

Comment: @Cmdd 
Thanks for your comment.
I am targeting 1.91.0.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enable SAVE button, you must set currentVariantSetModified to true.
For example:

```
this.byId("variantManagment").currentVariantSetModified(true);
```

I hope that I am helpful :)